# Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'last_visit'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

A keep getting this error in my mysql statement even though I'm not specifying a default value. Previous responses said adding a NOT NULL would fix it, but I still get the error. What is odd is if I switch the lines of date_joined and last_visit, I get the same error, except on date_joined. Any ideas why its giving this error? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE user_info(
user_id serial,
oauth_provider VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
oauth_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
date_of_birth date NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
gender char NOT NULL,
date_joined timestamp NOT NULL,
last_visit timestamp NOT NULL,
account_enabled boolean NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT user_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: WHat is your version of MYSQL

Comment: Maybe you shoudl read this page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html of the manual for the bersion of MYSQL you are using

Answer (score 0):

I use your code and me all work:
[image]

Comment: Yeah I'm using 5.7.11 so you probably have a different version. When I had 5.6 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL < 5.6 you cant have 2 timestamp column with same default values.

For MySQL 5.5 check this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html

> One TIMESTAMP column in a table can have the current timestamp as the default value for initializing the column, as the auto-update value, or both. It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column.

So if you want to have 2 column with timestamp try this.

```
CREATE TABLE user_info(
user_id serial,
oauth_provider VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
oauth_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
date_of_birth date NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
gender char NOT NULL,
date_joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMPL,
last_visit TIMESTAMP NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
account_enabled boolean NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT user_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```